# Function(depthwiseConvolution): missing threadgroupMemory binding at index 0 for lM[0]

Tags: metal, metal-performance-shaders

I'm trying to execute a simple DepthwiseConvolution kernel with Metal Performance Shaders on MacOS and have problems with it. First I initialize an `MPSImage` (called `debugInputImage`) with proper size filled with some number, say `1.0`. Then I create my convolutional kernel:

```
convolution_depthwise_0 = MPSCNNConvolution(device: device, 
    weights: datasource_depthwise_0)
```

Where `datasource_depthwise_0` is an instance of `MPSCNNConvolutionDataSource` with the following descriptor:

```
func descriptor() -> MPSCNNConvolutionDescriptor {
    var desc = MPSCNNDepthWiseConvolutionDescriptor(kernelWidth: 3,
        kernelHeight: 3,
        inputFeatureChannels: 32,
        outputFeatureChannels: 32)
    return desc
}
```

This is how I initialise the input image:

```
let imageDescriptor = MPSImageDescriptor(channelFormat: .float16, 
    width: 256, height: 256, featureChannels: 32)

debugInputImage = MPSImage(device: device, 
    imageDescriptor: imageDescriptor)

var arrayOfOnes = Array(repeating: Float(1.0), 
    count: imageDescriptor.width * imageDescriptor.height 
        * imageDescriptor.featureChannels)


let arrayOfOnes16 = toFloat16(&arrayOfOnes, size: arrayOfOnes.count)

debugInputImage.writeBytes(arrayOfOnes16, 
    dataLayout: MPSDataLayout.HeightxWidthxFeatureChannels, imageIndex: 0)
```

When I run all of this:

```
let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()!
let outImage = convolution_depthwise_0.encode(commandBuffer: commandBuffer, 
    sourceImage: debugInputImage)
```

And get this error (at this line `let outImage = convolution_depthwise_0.encode(...`):

```
validateComputeFunctionArguments:860: failed assertion `Compute 
Function(depthwiseConvolution): missing threadgroupMemory binding 
at index 0 for lM[0].'
```

For regular convolution everything is fine, only for Depthwise I get this problem.

What could be the reason for that error?

System: MacOS 10.14, XCode 10.1 beta 3

Only MPSCNNDepthWiseConvolutionDescriptor doesn't work. I have no problems with MPSCNNConvolutionDescriptor. I also have no problems on iOS, only Mac OS.

Comment: What OS are you running this on? I've been using depthwise convolutions a lot but haven't come across this error yet (on iOS anyway). It seems like an error in MPS. The only other thing I can think of is that perhaps your MPSImage is in a format not supported by the depthwise convolution.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans I am running it on MacOS. I have added it to the question. I haven't tried it on IOS yet but probably it's something I have to do.

Comment: Are your `inputFeatureChannels` and `outputFeatureChannels` the same value?

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans yes, they are the same. Updated values in the question. Otherwise (just for example) I get two kind of errors: "multipler not 1 is not supported" or "output should be multiple of input". :) So those errors look easily understandable.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans I also added information about the input image initialisation if it may be useful

Comment: ok I have some playground that works, now I'm trying to compare it with the one that does not work :)

Comment: It seems to work on xcode playground but fails when you try to run the same code for application..

Comment: Is the validation layer enabled for a playground?

Comment: @KenThomases that's probably the reason, thank you for suggestion. I could not validate whether Metal API Validation is enabled quickly, I could not find schemes for the playground. I'll try to check it soon.

Comment: So it works on iOS, with Metal API Validation enabled. It looks like mac os only problem.

Comment: It's a bug. Try newer OS revision.